# How to get data from spring controller to angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Here is Controller:

This is my spring controller pagefrom this i need to get my values and posted in my jsp page using angular js.i tried lot to get this deatils by passing like JSON but its not working.please someone help how to get details from the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody void  search(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {

 List<Employee> data =  employeeService.listEmployeess();
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
       for (Employee e : data) {
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(e);
           array.put(jsonObject);
       }
    res.getWriter().append(array.toString());

   }
```

My JSP page :

This is my jsp page here im trying to get my data's from controller to my jsp page but its not working .it also doesn't throw any error msg.simply data is not displaying.

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Spring MVC + AngularJS Demo</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
angular.module("app",[])
        .controller("Hello",function ($scope,$http){
     $scope.getData = function() {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html').
                success(function(response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.data;
                });
        }
    });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">

        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>salary</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>BloodGrp</th>
        <th>Aids</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

<tbody  ng-controller="Hello" ng-init="getData ()">
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"> 
 <td>{{employee.empId}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.empName}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.empAge}}</td> 
   <td>{{employee.salary}}</td> 
   <td>{{employee.empAddress}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.bloodgrp}}</td> 
    <td>{{employee.aids}}</td>
     <td>{{employee.weight}}</td> 
     </tr> </tbody> 
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your request url should be the right uri like 
 $http.get('http ://localhost:8080/sub') ?

Comment: sorry bro wait this i put for sample orginal data i will edit wait

Comment: Bro in this if i use the url seperately its working

Comment: [{"empId":1,"bloodgrp":"0-ve","empName":"krishnaKumars","weight":78,"aids":"negative","empAge":23,"salary":15000,"empAddress":"madurai"},{"empId":2,"bloodgrp":"o-ve","empName":"Archanasundar","weight":68,"aids":"Negative","empAge":31,"salary":50000,"empAddress":"chennai"}]

Comment: if i trying to paste in jsp its not working im strucked for 2 weeks

Comment: Please do not use that version of angularjs it is like 7 years old. Use 1.6

Comment: im new to this.im fresher i do no how to do please send me the code bro

Comment: What is the result messege of your console when using   console.log(JSON.stingify(response.data)); or alert(JSON.stringify(response.data) ? If you have a correct message then you must check the employees object.

Comment: sorry i didint use console.log(JSON.stingify(response.data));

Comment: Nothing is displaying

Comment: Please help me bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$http.get('http ://localhost:8080/search')` is the correct URL to get the data which is

```
[
   {"empId":1,"bloodgrp":"0-ve","empName":"krishnaKumars","wei‌​ght":78,"aids":"nega‌​tive","empAge":23,"s‌​alary":15000,"empAdd‌​ress":"madurai"},
   {"e‌​mpId":2,"bloodgrp":"‌​o-ve","empName":"Arc‌​hanasundar","weight"‌​:68,"aids":"Negative‌​","empAge":31,"salar‌​y":50000,"empAddress‌​":"chennai"}
]
```

then write like this

```
$http.get('http ://localhost:8080/search')
          .success(function(response) {
                $scope.employees = response;
            });
    }
```

And you are using very old version of AngularJs. Please move to latest version like 1.6.5 then you have to write like

```
$http.get('http ://localhost:8080/search')
          .then(function(response) {
                $scope.employees = response.data;
            });
    }
```

Comment: That also not working bro i got irritated for 2 weeks im not getting any clue

Comment: any error in console? or what are the observations from your side?

Comment: is there any other way to get data from controller

Comment: Are you getting your response in any rest client like postman? Do you have any Authorization?

Comment: for going to my searc.jsp page i mapped using url "/iwill.html" in that jsp page im having  the above coding in that im using url "/search.html" which contains my data. When i click search button my jsp page displaying with url "/iwill.html" not with "/search.html"

Comment: which routing are you using? frontEnd side (ng-router/ui-router) or backend side

Comment: im using ng-router